# dicionary filled with dataframes restructuring

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to restructure a dictionary which is filled with multiple dataframes. I have found a solution, but as I am new to Python, it is a rather primitive one. Because my solution is very slow when I increase the number of dataframes inside my dictionary, I wanted to ask if anyone know how to improve my existing code or knows an alternative solution:

I have a dictionary which is made up of three df's with info about a country. To give an example:

```
# example dictionary filled with dataframes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dic_old={}

countries = ['USA', 'China', 'India']
col = ['factor 1','factor 2','factor 3']
ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(start ='2019-01-10', freq ='m',  periods = 5) 

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3),columns=col, index = ind)    
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3),columns=col, index = ind)
df3=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3),columns=col, index = ind)

dic_old['USA']=df1
dic_old['China']=df2
dic_old['India']=df3
```

Now I would like to restructure this dictionary. Instead of having 3 dataframes with the information of each separate country, I would now like to have a dataframe for each date with the info of all countries. So my dictionary would change from 3 dataframes with 5 rows à 3 columns, to a new dictionary with 5 dataframes and 3 rows à 3 columns. I managed to do this with the following code:

```
dates = ind.tolist()
factors = dic_old['USA'].columns
dic_new = {}

# Create empty dataframes with desired column headers and index
for d in dates:
    dic_new[d.strftime('%Y-%m')] = pd.DataFrame(index=countries, columns = factors) #

# fill empty dataframes with info from dic_old
for y in dates:
    for e in countries:
        dic_new[y.strftime('%Y-%m')].loc[e] = dic_old[e].loc[y]
```

Now if I increase the number of dataframes (lets say I add more countries and more dates), then my piece of code becomes very slow. This is probably no surprise considering that I use 3 for loops which are known to be rather slow. Does anyone know how I could make my code run faster or does anyone see an alternative to solving my problem?

thanks in advance, any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the design of your program. 
Why not having only one DataFrame instead?

Take a look to the append method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)) or the concat method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)).

If you want to replicate data fast, use merge method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)) with two dataframes (i.e. dates and factors) using a dummy key (i.e. `df["key"]=0`) to perform a cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know the append and concat method, but because I have multiple factors combined with multiple countries and a time series, I need to have a 3D structure for my data. (X axis Factors, Y axis time and Z axis the different countries)

Comment: Then you should update your question accordingly, with a more specific title as well as adding some constrains like this one. Still I would use the previous solution, accesing it by country when you want to access to the X-axis with some value of Z axis for instance. `df[df["country"]=="USA"][factors]`